# Stripe APIからのPOST(Webhookのリッスン)がNginxで405エラーで弾かれる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws, api, nginx

Aws + Nginx + Rails(Puma)でシステムを構築しており、システム内にStripeの決済システムを導入しております。
Stripeの決済情報をもとにデータベース等への書き込みを行いたいため、Webhookを用いてStripeからのPOSTをリッスンしようとしておエラー内容
現状、stripeからの送信は正しくされていますが、こちらからのレスポンス405 (Method Not Allowed)となっており、Nginxではじかれている状態です。

Nginxを立ち上げず、PumaのみでRailsサーバーを起動すると、Webhookリッスンが200ステータスとなり正しく待ち受けができていることが確認できました。

405を200にして返す「error_page 405 =200 $uri;」をNginxファイルに記載してみたのですがエラーメッセージは特に変わりませんでした。

何か問題のある部分や適切な方法をご教示いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
#### エラー内容 ####

# Stripe GUI画面上
405 (Method Not Allowed)

# Nginx アクセスログ上
[8/Sep/2023:06:52:29 +0000] "POST /stripe/webhook HTTP/1.1" 405 166 "-" "Stripe/1.0 (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)"
```

```
# Nginxファイル
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    root /home/ubuntu/xxxxx/yyyyy/public;

    error_page 405 =200 $uri;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-CSRF-Token $http_x_csrf_token;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Client-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-SSL on;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/xxx-yyyy-puma.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: 自分の認識内ではnginxの設定への違和感はないので、Webアプリケーション側のHTTPステータスが405なのであれば、 Railsアプリケーション側で「/stripe/webhook へのPOSTリクエスト」を受け付けない実装になってしまっているように思えます。
一度Railsアプリの実装を見直した上で、解決が難しそうなら該当箇所のコードも掲載すると良いのではないでしょうか。